# Get a value in BeautifulSoup in nested HTML tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a webscraping to extract a value in a nested tag imported from the HTML file. Here is the snippet of the HTML

```
    <table class="Total_coverage" cellspacing="0" id="coveragetable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="sortable" id="a" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Element</td>
      <td class="down sortable bar" id="b" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Nike</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="c" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Value.</td>
      <td class="sortable bar" id="d" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Adidas</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="e" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Value.</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr1" id="f" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Russia</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="g" onclick="toggleSort(this)">UAE</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr1" id="h" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Japan</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="i" onclick="toggleSort(this)">India</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td class="bar">2323</td>
      <td class="ctr2">12%</td>
      <td class="bar">233</td>
      <td class="ctr2">61%</td>
      <td class="ctr1">222</td>
      <td class="ctr2">322</td>
      <td class="ctr1">233</td>
       <td class="ctr2">455</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
```

I want to extract the 12% in the `<td class="ctr2">12%</td>`.  I tried with the below below step and got all value under  `</tfoot>` as  `<tfoot><tr><td>Total</td><td class="bar">2323</td><td class="ctr2">12%</td><td class="bar"> 233</td>.... </tfoot>`

```
with open('index.html', 'r') as f:

    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
    mydivs = soup.select_one("tfoot", {"class": "ctr2"})
    print("mydivs", mydivs)
```

Then I tried the below script and got `<td class="ctr2">12%</td>`

```
    mydivs = soup.select_one('td[class="ctr2"]')
    print("mydivs", mydivs)
```

Let me know where I am missing and How to get the only 12% and also all the values in td. I am using Python to extract the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the only 12% and also all the values in td. I am using Python to extract the data

Cause question is not that focused and expected output not that clear, there are a lot of ways to get the data.

---

Get all the values in your `tfoot` as `list` using `stripped_strings`:

```
list(soup.tfoot.stripped_strings)
#['Total', '2323', '12%', '233', '61%', '222', '322', '233', '455']
```

Get your explicit value while picking by `index`:

```
list(soup.tfoot.stripped_strings)[2]
#12%
```

Get your explicit value by `css selector` directly:

```
soup.select_one('tfoot td:nth-of-type(3)').text
#12%
```

or

```
soup.select_one('tfoot td.ctr2').text
#12%
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
  <table class="Total_coverage" cellspacing="0" id="coveragetable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="sortable" id="a" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Element</td>
      <td class="down sortable bar" id="b" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Nike</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="c" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Value.</td>
      <td class="sortable bar" id="d" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Adidas</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="e" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Value.</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr1" id="f" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Russia</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="g" onclick="toggleSort(this)">UAE</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr1" id="h" onclick="toggleSort(this)">Japan</td>
      <td class="sortable ctr2" id="i" onclick="toggleSort(this)">India</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td class="bar">2323</td>
      <td class="ctr2">12%</td>
      <td class="bar">233</td>
      <td class="ctr2">61%</td>
      <td class="ctr1">222</td>
      <td class="ctr2">322</td>
      <td class="ctr1">233</td>
       <td class="ctr2">455</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(list(soup.tfoot.stripped_strings))

print(list(soup.tfoot.stripped_strings)[2])
```

###### Output

```
['Total', '2323', '12%', '233', '61%', '222', '322', '233', '455']

12%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the text inside the `div` using `mydivs.text`

Comment: Thanks for your input. This provides text all the value in the mydivs like Total2323 12%23361%222322233455

Comment: ```mydivtext = soup.select_one('td[class="ctr2"]').text```

Comment: (Don't comment comments: Improve your posts.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
    mydivs = soup.select_one('td[class="ctr2"]').text
    print("mydivs", mydivs)
```